# Most times Ubuntu doesn't see my second HD

Tags: 16.04, 32-bit, lts

I am running

- a Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2160 @ 1.80GHz × 2
- with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit

Most times Ubuntu doesn't see my second HD. How can I see the files on it or create a shortcut in the taskbar?

Comment: Do you want that second HD automatically mounted on boot? If so -> check out `/etc/fstab`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to leave a comment, so will just ask you some questions here in the answer section, and I'll make some suggestions:

1. When you say *"most times"* it doesn't see your second hard drive, does that mean that sometimes it does?
2. Is your second hard drive an external drive you're plugging in to a USB port?
3. How is the drive formatted? Do you know if it's NTFS or EXT4 or something else?

**Some things you can try:**

1. If it's an external drive, try to get one of those USB cables that has two USB connectors that plug in to your computer (one is to boost the amount of power to the device).
2. Get a terminal up and enter the following to see what drives (and partitions) are available:

   sudo lsblk -f

Do you see your drive listed there? If so, what is the **NAME**, **FSTYPE** and **UUID**?

If the results from (2) above are:

```
NAME: sdb1
FSTYPE: ntfs
UUID: 04153E43129F3EDA
```

You could (while still in the terminal) create a *mount point* in your /mnt directory using:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/drive2
```

From here, mount the partition using:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/drive2
```

You should then be able to use Nautilus to navigate to /mnt/drive2 to see the files on that NTFS partition. Of course, use the appropriate mount type (-t). For example, if your drive is partitioned with the EXT4 filesystem, using:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/drive2
```

Once you have figured out you can manually mount your partition(s) as above, you can then permanently add the mount in your /etc/fstab, but first "unmount" the partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/drive2
```

Then use a text editor to modify /etc/fstab:

```
sudo vi /etc/fstab
```

then add the line:

```
UUID=04153E43129F3EDA   /mnt/ntfs      ntfs      defaults 0 2
```

Save the file and quit back to the terminal (by pressing **:** then **w** then **q** then ), then run "mount all" using:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Just to recap:

1. To manually mount, you'll need a) the name of the partition, and b) the FSTYPE (filesystem type).
2. To add a permanent mount, you'll need a) the name of the partition, b) the FSTYPE (filesystem type), and c) the UUID of the partition.

Comment: thanks so much Scott Deagan  most of your directions where over my head as Im a first time ubantu user but my problem seem to have solved itself  it was not seeing my 250 gig internal hd  the drive has at least 3 partitions on it a 50 gb ntfs  a 100 gb fat and a 100 gb ntfs  on a fresh install of Ubuntu it saw it fine then it quit seeing it and my boot up time went from 1.5 minutes to over 5 minutes  now it seems to see it every time and my boot time is back to 1.5 minutes I update my os every day my guess is a update glitch that has since been fixed? thanks again